# Have to make a customized dataframe from a dict with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

Please find below my input/output :

##### INPUT :

```
dico = {'abc': 'val1=343, val2=935',
'def': 'val1=95, val2=935',
'ghi': 'val1=123, val2=508'}
```

##### OUTPUT (desired) :

[image]

I tried with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dico, index=dico.keys)` but unfortunately I got an error.

> TypeError: DataFrame.from_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'index'

Do you have any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use a regex pattern to find the matching pairs corresponding to each value in the input dictionary then convert the pairs to `dict` and create a new dataframe

```
import re

pd.DataFrame([dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)=(\d+)', v)) for k, v in dico.items()], dico)
```

Alternative pandas only approach with `extractall` (might be slower):

```
pd.Series(dico).str.extractall(r'(\S+)=(\d+)').droplevel(1).pivot(columns=0, values=1)
```

##### Result

```
    val1 val2
abc  343  935
def   95  935
ghi  123  508
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

```
records = []
for key,vals in dico.items():
    vals = [ tuple(v.strip().split("=")) for v in vals.split(",")]
    records.append(dict(vals))
#records:
#[{'val1': '343', 'val2': '935'},
# {'val1': '95', 'val2': '935'},
# {'val1': '123', 'val2': '508'}]

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(records, index=dico.keys())

#    val1 val2
#abc  343  935
#def   95  935
#ghi  123  508
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import re

dd = {key: list(map(str, re.sub('val\d=', '', value).replace(' ', '').split(','))) for key, value in dico.items()}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='index', columns=['val1', 'val2'])
```

###### # Output :

```
print(df)

    val1 val2
abc  343  935
def   95  935
ghi  123  508
```

###### # Intermediates :

```
print(dd)

{'abc': ['343', '935'], 'def': ['95', '935'], 'ghi': ['123', '508']}
```